# How to query nested heterogeneous document

Tags: mongodb

I have an array that have this format:

```
data{
  [sequentialId]{guid:value1,name:value2}
}
```

I need to do something like db.data.find("data.?.name":"value1")

All the solutions I've seen don't work because they are expecting me to know the name of the attribute, but in this case the ID is sequential.

I've looked at the standard way of querying nested documents described here
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/
I also looked at some options like $unwind but I can't get anything to work

here's a small sample

```
{"41":{"b":453081600,"f":1,"h":171,"s":4,"w":4,"wr":[2,0]},
"80":{"b":337132800,"f":2,"h":169,"s":4,"w":4,"wr":[0,0]},
"388":{"b":148694400,"f":1,"h":188,"l":{"c":[{"e":2001,"g":13,"m":292,"s":1992,"t":18},{"e":2006,"g":11,"m":197,"s":2001,"t":1},{"e":2009,"g":2,"m":111,"s":2006,"t":1790},{"e":2009,"g":0,"m":1,"s":2009,"t":1937},{"e":2010,"g":1,"m":14,"s":2010,"t":1},{"e":2011,"g":0,"m":8,"s":2010,"t":13}],"n":[{"e":2007,"g":1,"m":73,"s":1996,"t":1318}]},"s":2,"w":3,"wr":[0,0]}}
```

for example in this set of data I might need to query all the docs where "f"=1

Comment: Can you provide sample of actual data, I take try on it !!

Comment: (EDIT: Pushing sample to the top so I can format it)

Comment: Are all these are individual objects in a document or in an array of a field of a document, or in different documents ?

Comment: Data is a JSON dump I was provided @srinivasy

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

***Note:** We are fetching the documents which have `name` is equal to `a`*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields:{
      "filtered":{
        $filter:{
          "input":"$data",
          "as":"info",
          "cond":{
            $let:{
              "vars":{
                "array":{
                  $objectToArray:"$$info"
                }
              },
              "in":{
                $in:["a","$$array.v.name"]
              }
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match:{
      "filtered.0":{
        $exists:true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "filtered":0
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "41": {
        "b": 453081600,
        "name": "a"
      },
      "80": {
        "b": 337132800,
        "name": "b"
      },
      "388": {
        "b": 148694400,
        "name": "c"
      }
    }
  ]
}
{
  "data":[
    {
      "41": {
        "b": 453081600,
        "name": "b"
      },
      "80": {
        "b": 337132800,
        "name": "b"
      },
      "388": {
        "b": 148694400,
        "name": "c"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "41": {
        "b": 453081600,
        "name": "a"
      },
      "80": {
        "b": 337132800,
        "name": "b"
      },
      "388": {
        "b": 148694400,
        "name": "c"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Query analysis:**

- We are creating a filtered array to hold only those records from `data` array which contains `name` equal to `a` inside any subdocument with an unknown key.
- It's done by first converting each document of `data` into an array of key-value pairs. Now we can directly query the values without worrying about the keys.
- Finally, filter those documents in which the size of `filtered` array is greater than zero.